# Speed up calculation

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

First of all

**thanks to:**

**rm -rf,  Mr.Wizard, Simon Woods, Pickett, Piotr Wendykier, Mac, Yves Klett, belisarius, halirutan, bill s,  nikie, wxffles, ...**

Everybody of you helped me (a mathematica beginner) to solve my image overlapping problem.

Now I would like to show you the outcome and would ask you if there is a way to make my code faster.

The images and the notebook file can be downloaded here:

```
http://goo.gl/LAV1me
```

The code also shown here:

```
imageDir = FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "images"}];

SetDirectory[imageDir];
fNames = FileNames["*.png"];  

numFiles = Length[fNames]; 

readImage[ index_] := Import[fNames[[index]]]; 

number = 50;
img = readImage[1];
superImg = ImageData[ImageMultiply[img, 0]];

 For[
    i = 1, i < number + 1, i++,
    img = readImage[i];
    ind = Position[ImageData[Binarize[img, 0.18]], 1];
     superImg = ReplacePart[superImg, ind -> 1/number*i];
    ]
imageOut = 
 Colorize[Image[superImg], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems quicker. Importing the images is the slowest bit, there's probably not much you can do about that.

```
fNames = FileNames["*.png"]; 
n = Length @ fNames;

bins = Table[
   Clip[Import[fNames[[i]], "GrayLevels"], {0.18, 0.18}, {0, i/n}] ,
   {i, n}];

Colorize[
 Image[Map[Max, Transpose[bins, {3, 1, 2}], {2}]],
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

Comment: @belisarius, the pixels injected into OP's `superImg` increase in value as the image list is stepped through. So the final value in any pixel is always the maximum.

Comment: Yep, I think this is more efficient than mine. I tried to emulate the OP's logic, and this is better

Comment: Dear Simon, I exchanged Table by ParallelTable and it makes your code 80% faster ..

Answer (score 6):

This one takes less than one third of the time in my machine. The main idea is NOT converting to `ImageData[]` to speed up image ops.

```
imgs = Import /@ fNames; 
fun[img_, idx_] := ImageApply[UnitStep[# - .18]/number idx &, img]; 
imgs1 = MapIndexed[fun[#1, #2[[1]]] &, imgs];
fold = Fold[ ImageAdd[ImageSubtract[#1, ImageMultiply[#1, Binarize[#2, 0]]], #2] &, imgs1];
imageOut1 = Colorize[fold, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may see there are very small deviations  wrt your method (I haven't looked much into them, but they shouldn't be very difficult to spot and correct if there is need for it at all):

```
ImageSubtract[imageOut, imageOut1] // ImageData // Flatten // Abs // Max
(* 0.00784314 *)
```

Comment: Perhaps the folding operation could be carried along with the Duff-Porter operators of `ImageCompose[]`, but I haven't tried.

Comment: Dear belisarius,

Comment: in the 4th line (fold= ...) after "img1" and "]" Mathematica says something is missing? Do you have the same warning?

Comment: >>" Too few arguments given"
But I can execute the code .... hmmm

Comment: @MilenkoRubin-Zuzic That's probably because I'm using a syntax variant for `Fold[]` with two arguments instead of three. Not documented but cool :)