# Visualization of traces of moving objects

Tags: performance-tuning, image-processing

**An example movie which is made with the listed mathematica code below shows traces of moving objects:**

https://youtu.be/8jN2uuSHCEg (Melting ...)

http://youtu.be/5ET62846C-I (Crystallisation ...)

The following question is related to:

[Speed up calculation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69305/speed-up-calculation)

1. I have thousands of gray scale images.
2. I want to superpose `image_1` to `image_50`, `image_2` to `image_51`, `image_3` to `image_52`, ..., `image_951` to `image_1000`, ... This is always a set of `50 images`.
3. For the superposition each image is binarized and then colorized differently. The resulting images are `col_Image_1`, `col_Image_2`, ... `col_Image_50`. The color is varying from `col_Image_1` to `col_Image_50` following a certain color table (see below).
4. Here is a set of 3 images to illustrate the superposition of circular shaped objects: `col_Image_1` has only black and blue pixels, `col_Image_2` has only black and green pixels and `col_Image_3` has only black and red pixels.

[image]

The superposed image shows red over green over blue:

[image]

Here you can find a set of 200 gray scale images.
http://bit.ly/1CpyIK1 (12.5 MB)

These images I have analyzed with the following code (which produces the expected resulting images (200 images yield 151 superposed images), but is still relatively slow). I have a 4 core i7 processor and have used ParallelTable. For calculating 151 images and writing them to files it takes around 110 sec.

The (until now fastest) solution for the superposition is from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods

```
bins = Table[
   Clip[Import[fNames[[i]], "GrayLevels"], {0.18, 0.18}, {0, 
     i/number}], {i, number}];
superImg = 
  Colorize[Image[Map[Max, Transpose[bins, {3, 1, 2}], {2}]], 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &)];
```

My code is given here, which I would like to make faster is here:

```
ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[imageDir], "Directory"], 
   Dynamic[imageDir]}];

colTable = {{Black}, 
  Table[{Blend[{Blue, Green, Yellow, Red}, x]}, {x, 1/255, 1, 
    1/255}]}; colTable = Flatten[colTable];

SetDirectory[imageDir];
fNames = FileNames["*.png"];

numFiles = Length[fNames];
number = 50;


ParallelTable[

 bins = Table[
   Clip[Import[fNames[[i + j]], "GrayLevels"], {0.25, 0.25}, {0, 
     i/number}], {i, 1, number}];
 superImg = 
  Colorize[Image[Map[Max, Transpose[bins, {3, 1, 2}], {2}]], 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[colTable, #] &)];

 fileName = 
  StringJoin[imageDir, "/out_", ToString[j + 1], ".png"];

 Export[fileName, superImg, "PNG"];

 , {j, 0, numFiles - number}

 ]
```

You can download all the superposed images here: http://bit.ly/1CoXsSr (15.7 MB)

For example superposed image no. 66 (out of 151 images) is:

[image]

A superposition using all 200 images (number = 200) yields:

[image]

> And now my question: Can my mathematica code be optimized/faster?

Comment: your links don't work

Comment: please try it again ... are they working now?

Comment: Not sure, but [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35531/7167) might be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure if anyone will readily download 40-230 MB large zip-files. A smaller sample might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The zip-files are now 13 MB, 12.5 MB, 15.7 MB

Comment: Have you tried `Compile`?

Comment: How would that be implemented?

Comment: Your chances of getting help would be much higher if you could isolate your problem: Find the line or lines (2-3 lines, not 20 lines) that take most of the time, and post some code that can be benchmarked with e.g. a random matrix. (That would also make potential answers more usable to other people.) And really: if you want to improve performance, finding out where the bottleneck is should be your first step anyway.